# What does the “+” operator do in Java?

Tags: java

Please someone explain the ("x = " + x) part of the code.

```
public class While-With-Nested-If {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    int x = 1;
    while(x < 100) {
      System.out.println("x = " + x);
      if(x % 2 == 0) {
        x++;
      } else {
        x *= 2;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ["Concatenates two strings"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) - follow along with a book/tutorial, there be much *much* more to learn.

Comment: [This is how it works](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/08/compiler-version-string-concatenation.html)

Comment: Your class name is not a valid identifier. Therefore the `("x = " + x)` does the same as the rest of the code, i.e. nothing (since it doesn't compile).

Answer (score 1):

In this case the operator is used to concatenate a string with the string representation of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it concatenates a `String` with the string representation of `x`. For example: `x = 42;`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the operand type.

For `String` type operands it creates a new `String` instance (`String` objects are immutable) and assigns to it the concatenation of two operands.

For numeric types it works as addition operator.

Comment: +1, best answer here, thank you! I even forget it creates a new string instance

Answer (score 0):

The "+" operator acts as syntactic sugar for the concatenation operator in regards to String operations.

Comment: Please explain that a bit. I always thought the `+` operator was the concatenation operator. Also AFAIK it's the only way to make a concatenation happen at compile time (concatenation of constant expressions). Therefore it would be better to write a bit more than "it's syntactic sugar".

Comment: The unary + coerces primitives and classes such as Integers into strings. This means that you can put in the effort to do: "Example: 2 + ".concat(new Integer(3).toString()) to write the string "Example: 2 + 3". But instead, you can simple just use the + operator, "Example: 2 + " + 3, and it is the equivalent short hand. What you said about the `+` operator is correct, I just wanted to add that, as in this case, syntactic sugar is used to describe syntax added to a language to facilitate ease of use and  limiting the amount of duplication. Please let me know if you have any other questions!

Answer (score 0):

It is used to concatenate the two strings in your case.

When you write

```
String a = b + c + d;
```

then it gets converted into:

```
String a = new StringBuilder(b).append(c).append(d).toString();
```

You may refer [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) for more details

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator concatenates if the operands' type is string, and it performs summing if the operands are `int`s, `float`s or `double`s.

Here is the out put:
X = 1, X = 2, X = 3, X = 6, X = 7, X = 14, X = 15, X = 30, X = 31, X = 62, X = 63...

Comment: I would like to add `long` as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this code block `while` loop will iterate till `x` is less than `100` in order to print all the values of `x` during "while" loop executes the `System.out.println("x = " + x);` is used.

Here java will send each value of `x` to output console by appending it to the `"x = "` string(text) so on each iteration of `while` loop you will get output on console like

```
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3

and so on...

x = 99
```

Comment: While the first 3 lines are correct, the last line certainly is not, since the last number that is printed is 63, not 99. The loop alternates between incrementing `x` and multiplying `x` with 2.